# Maximum error in a measurement?

Tags: error-analysis

Suppose a quantity $Z$ is given by $Z = x \pm \Delta{y}$, then what is the maximum error in the quantity $Z$? Is it $\Delta{y}$ or 2$\Delta{y}$?

Comment: How has $\Delta y$  been obtained?

Answer (score 1):

Error is defined as the difference between the measured value and the true value.  In your example it looks as though the experimenters believe that the true value is $x$ and the error is $\Delta y$.

However it's possible that the difference is larger.  Usually error is given in terms of the standard deviation $\sigma$,  e.g. $324 \pm20 N$ where the $20N$ is the one standard deviation error.

That leaves the possibility that the error is larger than $20N$ and may have a distribution like this

[image]